# gmpxx.h error on MAC

Tags: c++

I have used gmp-4.3.1 library.

Used following command to build library on MAC

1. `./configure --enable-cxx --enable-alloca=reentrant`
2. `make`
3. `make check`
4. `sudo make install`

It gives result `gmp.h, gmpxx.h, libgmp.a, libgmpxx.a`

I used this library for large number
When I use this library in my project it gives error like

```
gmpxx.h:1366: error: 'mp_get_memory_functions' was not declared in this scope
```

Please help me.

Comment: We can't find bugs in code we don't see.